# Сортировка списка. Лисп

Tags: lisp

Пока есть такой код

```
(defun Sort (l)
(
 cond
( (null l) '(Список отсортирован!) )
(  T ( rplaca (car l) (Min l) )  ( Sort( cdr l )    ))
)
)

(defun Min (l)
( cond
( (null l) nil)
( (eq (length l) 1) (car l) )
( T (Min2 (car l) (Min(cdr l) )))
)
)

(defun Min2 (x y)
( cond
( (<  x y ) x)
( T y)
)
)
```

Функция на поиск минимума правильно работает, а Sort при вызове например (Sort '( 3 2 1))
возвращет nil  и пишет bad argument type - 3. Это почему?

Comment: сделайте отступы как принято, сложно читать. Здесь: http://lisper.ru/pcl/syntax-and-semantics есть описание форматирования Lisp кода, придерживайтесь пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это не сортировка, а что-то странное.

Начнем с того, что `(rplaca (car l) …)`, если `l` простой список — это бессмыслица. Допустим, у нас есть список `l`:

```
(setf l '(3 2 1))
```

Визуально это можно представить, скажем, как (прямоугольники — cons'ы):

```
 ┌───┬─────────────────────┐
 │   │ ┌───┬─────────────┐ │
 │   │ │   │ ┌───┬─────┐ │ │
 │ 3 │ │ 2 │ │ 1 │ nil │ │ │
 │   │ │   │ └───┴─────┘ │ │
 │   │ └───┴─────────────┘ │
 └───┴─────────────────────┘

 └─┬─┘└─────────┬──────────┘
(car l)      (cdr l)
```

Я тут рисовал не цепочкой (как обычно рисуют, и как более правильно все это отображать), а вложенно. С псевдографикой, увы, неудобно по-другому.

Или, в виде утверждений:

```
(car l) => 3
(cdr l) => (2 1)
(car (cdr l)) => 2
(cdr (cdr l)) => (1)
(car (cdr (cdr l))) => 1
(cdr (cdr (cdr l))) => nil
```

Делая `(rplaca (car l) …)` Вы, по сути, делаете `(rplaca 3 …)`, но `3` — это не cons. Вот почему и получается «bad argument type - 3». Тип первого аргумента у `rplaca` неправильный.

А закончим тем, что даже если бы подразумевалось «заменить первый элемент в l (по сути, `(car l)`, да) на минимальное значение в `l` (т.е. `(rplaca l (min l))`), и потом рекурсивно отсортировать хвост», то это будет не сортировка. Вы заменяете первый элемент `l`, теряя значение, которое там было — это же не перенос и не перестановка, а замена-присвоение.

Еще раз, подробно, перечитайте все, что посвящено спискам в Lisp. Что есть cons, и как устроены (связанные) списки, и как работает `rplaca` (в частности, какие у нее аргументы) с примерами использования.

И, да, пожалуйста, форматируйте код более читаемо.

Comment: а нет какой-нибудь функции которая меняет местами 2 элемента в списке? тогда бы можно вместо rplaca ее написать..

Comment: Ясно. Ну тогда связка setf и nth поможет. Одно значение во временную переменную, второе на его место, и из временной переменной назад, на место второго.

Comment: я бы ей не отвечал пока не отформатирует код

Comment: Суровый ответ крутого лиспоида. @АннаХотико что это за XLISP такой, (википедия говорит, что это расширенная Scheme старой, R3RS версии)

Comment: drdaeman, и как же вы представляет перемену местами 2 элементов с помощью nth  и  setf?

Comment: @АннаХатико: Ну, например, хотя бы так:

    (defmacro swap-items (a1 a2)
        `(let ((temp ,a1))
             (setf ,a1 ,a2)
             (setf ,a2 temp)))
    
    (setf test-list '(3 2 1 4))
    (print test-list)                                 ; => (3 2 1 4)
    (swap-items (nth 1 test-list) (nth 2 test-list))
    (print test-list)                                 ; => (3 1 2 4)
    (swap-items (car test-list) (cadr test-list))
    (print test-list)                                 ; => (1 3 2 4)

Правда, я не уверен, что это правильный подход. Я с традициями Lisp'ов мало знаком.

Comment: Гм. Во-первых, посмотрите сообщение об ошибке и синтаксис `let`. Зачем квотить `vera`? Читайте сообщения об ошибках, они все объясняют: `let` ругается, что ему подали `quote vera` (т.е. `'vera`), а это не то, что он ожидает.

Во-вторых, это не будет работать. `setq` потрогает переменные внутри функции, в ее области видимости, и не более того. Это та причина, по которой я использовал макру.

Тогда уж, на худой конец:

    (defun swap-first-two (lst)
      (let ((temp (car lst)))
        (setf (car lst) (cadr lst))
        (setf (cadr lst) temp)))

Comment: протестировала вашу функцию в действии..


    (defun swap (lst) 
    (let ((temp (car lst))) 
    (setf (car lst) (cadr lst)) 
    (setf (cadr lst) temp))) 


исходный список s (3 2 1 4)
(swap s) пищет error:bad place form
Список становится s (2 2 1 4 )

Comment: Значит в XLisp что-то по-другому. Я, за неимением оного, проверял на Common Lisp'е, как ближайшем похожем доступном. Увы, я не знаю, что ему не нравится в последней строке. И тут лимит комментариев.